# How do I refactor this function in ELM?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am trying to pick up functional programming and decided to start with Problem 1 on Project Euler: basically add all numbers less than 1000 divisible by 3 or 5 (link: [a link](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1/)).

This is the code that I have written.  It outputs a list of factors of 3 or 5 (still need to figure out how to sum).

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Array

main =
  text (
toString
[findSum_maxZ 3 5 1000]
  )

findSum_maxZ x y max_z =
  Array.filter isDivisible_x_or_y (Array.initialize max_z identity)

isDivisible_x_or_y x = 
  if x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 then True else False
```

My issue is that I reference 3 and 5 twice but I cannot call isDivisible with the additional parameters of the more abstract 'x' and'y'.  My goal is to determine effective methods of removing these artificially mutable values so the end user only has to modify each input value once.  Any advice?

I apologize if this question is dumb, there is not a lot of information on ELM available (especially compared to python, c, c++, java, etc which I have used) and I am still not fully comfortable with the functional programming jargon.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I have seen examples of this in JS, but not sure how to make the translation to ELM

Comment: Just curious. Have you tried other solutions to the problem? There are at least 2 other ways to solve it without using an Array/List. Also, if you want to learn how to design programs in a way that will help you with Elm then I highly recommend http://www.htdp.org/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cool thing about ML languages is that you are pretty much free to build your own "dialect" to solve problems.

You can use currying to apply just the `x` and `y` arguments to your function, creating a new function where the supplied values are already set.

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Array

main = [findSum 3 5 1000]
           |>toString
           |>text

findSum x y maxZ =
      let
         isDivisibleByX = isDivisible x
         isDivisibleByY = isDivisible y
      in
         Array.initialize maxZ identity
         |>Array.filter isDivisibleByX
         |>Array.filter isDivisibleByY
         --as you can see, it is possible to use a list instead of creating
         --new functions, it is up to you to check which abstraction works
         --the best


isDivisible a b =
      b % a == 0
```

You can also work with a single function, without resorting to currying:

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Array

main = [findSum 3 5 1000]
       |>toString
       |>text

findSum x y maxZ =
     Array.initialize maxZ identity
     |>Array.filter (\n-> isDivisible x n ) --or just (isDivisible x)
     |>Array.filter (\n-> isDivisible y n)


isDivisible a b =
  b % a == 0
```

If you want to filter the array with just one line, you can do this:

```
import Html exposing (text)

main = findSum 3 5 1000
       |>toString
       |>text

findSum x y maxZ =
     let
        divisibles = \n-> isDivisible x n && isDivisible y n
     in
       List.range 0 maxZ 
       |>List.filter divisibles

isDivisible a b =
  b % a == 0
```

Comment: thoughtful, comprehensive, beautiful

Comment: @lfarroco Your `findSum_maxZ` takes an `x` and `y` but doesn't use it in the body of the function. Did you forget to replace the 3 with `x` and the 5 with `y` in the body?

Comment: On a lesser note, we tend not to use underscores in function names.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to apply the parameters, going to edit the answers with this and the underscore adjustment

Answer (score 2):

The most direct answer to your question is that you can have `isDivisible_x_or_y` take the two factors, and then use currying to pass the partially applied function to `Array.filter`.

That is, you can define `isDivisible_x_or_y` like this (I also removed the `if True then True else False` syntax and just return the expression directly):

```
isDivisible_x_or_y x y val =
    val % x == 0 || val % y == 0
```

Currying is the ability to only supply some of the parameters to a function, and get back a function that takes the rest of the parameters.  So, the type definition of `isDivisible_x_or_y` is `Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool` (that is, it takes in three `Int` values and returns a `Bool`).  If we supply values for the `x` and `y` arguments (e.g. `isDivisible_x_y 3 5`), we now get a function with the type definition of `Int -> Bool`.   This is the type expected by `Array.filter`.

You can see a working example at https://ellie-app.com/sdxWFL9ynka1

Another couple of notes:

`List` is much more common than `Array` in Elm.  You would only use `Array` if you need to get items at specific indexes.  Instead of `Array.initialize`, you can use `List.range`

Using the pipeline operator `|>` can often make your code a lot simpler to read.  Instead of `text (toString (getValue))`, you have `getValue |> toString |> text`, which is now in the order that the operations occur, and doesn't have extra parenthesis.  This whole program could be one simple pipeline (in a lot of scenarios putting everything into one pipeline can be excessive, though):

```
main =
    List.range 0 max_z
        |> List.filter (isDivisible_x_or_y 3 5)
        |> toString
        |> text

isDivisible_x_or_y x y val =
    val % x == 0 || val % y == 0
```